# Configure SharePoint Product Configuration Wizard Issue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development

I have installed Sharepoint 2013 in one Windows Server and SQL Server installed in another windows server.

My Problem is when I configure *Specify configuration Database* settings in *Sharepoint product configuration wizard* it shows the error

> "The Username is invalid. The account must be a valid domain account"

and my SharePoint Server and SQL Server are running in domain account.

Please help me to solve the issue..

Comment: Does your domain account has machine Admin privileges on the server where SP & Sql were installed ? Also you add this account into the Sql server security folder -->logins --> add this domain account with checking the checkboxes for the appropriate roles.- processadmin,securadmin etc. Its recommended that, you need a domain account whose password never expires.

Comment: Thanks for reply..Yes My domain account have admin privileges on both server..Also i added the administrator account in SQL server under Security Folder with permissions of Processadmin and secureadmin..

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same error. It was caused that SharePoint only supports “Stand-alone” mode for non domain environments.

I followed the solution in the following post and solved the error.
http://nkdagility.com/issue-sharepoint-2013-the-username-is-invalid-the-account-must-be-a-valid-domain-account/

Comment: Thanks for reply.I tried you solution..But it is not working.In power shell it shows the error "Cannot connect to database master at SQL server at(Server name).the database might not exist,or the current user does not have permissions.

Answer (score 0):

There are account and group policy considerations when installing a SharePoint farm.  You have to make sure your accounts have the right permissions and the right administrative rights on the servers you are deploying your farm to just as @SaMoIPP alluded to in his comment.  Take a look [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/27655.sharepoint-2013-group-policy-considerations-for-a-sharepoint-farm.aspx)  to see what you need for group policy.  There is also a link within the site that will lead you in the right direction for setting up your accounts for your farm.  It sounds like you need to get your service accounts in order.